# Bayesian belief network for finding combinatory effects of multiple environmental variables on allele frequency

Tags: r, bayesian, bayesian-network

I'm a beginner to Bayesian belief network (BBN). I read a few articles on introduction to BBN. So I know a general idea of BBN. But I'm struggling to construct a graphical network and conditional probability table (CPT) with my data set. A main aim of my research is to find any combinatory (synergistic, additive, antagonistic) effects of multiple environmental variables on allele frequency of some genetic loci. Please go to [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tx9q5v68fgprbj7/environmental%20variables%20vs%20allele%20frequency.xlsx) to download a part of my data set. I have 15 environmental variables (each denoted as "var" in the excel sheet) and an allele frequency data (locus1 in the excel sheet) collected at 18 sites.

I made a pairwise correlation table of environmental data to see some interactions between the environmental variables but this does not provide information on combinatory effects of them on allele frequency (I think....). I would really appreciate it if you could give me any suggestions on how to make a network graph and CPT with my data set. I use R. So if it's easier to guide me with R scripts, please do so.

Comment: As there are 15 variables, combinations can vary from 2 to 15 combinatory sets (e.g. var1+var2 or var1+var2+var3+var4+var5+var6.......+var15). So the number of combinations can be very large....